# iOS 7 - Take the value of a textField inside a custom tableViewCell from another function

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry if the title is not clear. I have an application that shows a tableView and the user selects several rows and inputs text in the textField in the tableViewCell. After that, he presses a button to submit his selections together with the his input in the textField.

Here is `SearchResultTableViewCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchResultTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *discount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *discountInput;

@end
```

And here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *ItemCellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    SearchResultTableViewCell *tableCell =(SearchResultTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ItemCellIdentifier];

    //set text labels here --> The values are taken from arrays
    [tableCell.price setText:[NSString stringWithString:[priceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [tableCell.itemName setText:[NSString stringWithString:[itemNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [tableCell.discount setText:[NSString stringWithString:[discountList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [tableCell.quantity setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
    [tableCell.discountInput setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];

    tableCell.itemName.numberOfLines = 0;
    tableCell.itemName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    //set check mark and highlights.
    if ([[checkList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue] == 1){
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                               animated:YES
                         scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

    }
    else{
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    return tableCell;

}
```

My issue lies in accessing the textField input from my own function. Here is my function so far:

```
-(void)prepareFinalArray{
    //these are the arrays where I save the selection
    itemNameListFinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    priceListFinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    discountListFinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    discountRequestListFinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //use this array to know which positions the selected items are
    NSMutableArray *selectedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //loop at the checkList. My checkList array tracks which rows are selected.
    for( int i = 0 ; i < [checkList count] ; i++ ){
        if( [checkList[i] isEqualToString:@"1"] ){
            NSNumber *currentElement = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:i];
            NSLog(@"Selected item detected at %d,", i);
            [selectedItems addObject:currentElement];
        }
    }

    //Now that we have the index paths, get the itemNames, discount, user input qty, and user input discount.
    for( int i = 0 ; i < [selectedItems count] ; i++){
        //now that I have the indices of the selected items, I get the value from my 
        //itemNameList and discountList arrays, these arrays were used to populate the tableView
        [itemNameListFinal addObject:itemNameList[[[selectedItems objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]]];
        [discountListFinal addObject:discountList[[[selectedItems objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]]];

        //This is my problem so far, what I want to do next is to access the tableViewCell
        //and their quantity and discountInput properties (the textFields)
        //so far, I managed to get the cell for row at a certain index path
        //I do not know how to proceed after this. 
        //[self.searchResults cellForRowAtIndexPath:[[[selectedItems objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]].row];
    }
}
```

I do not know how to proceed after this:

`[self.searchResults cellForRowAtIndexPath:[[[selectedItems objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]].row];`

I do not know how to access the `quantity` and `discountInput` properties once I have the row (assuming that I managed to get the row properly in the code above) and I'm not also sure on how to get the input text from them. Can anyone help me? Sorry if what I want to do is too tedious.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Tell me more about the cell, or paste its code here. Is it a normal UITableViewCell, or a subclass? Are the quantity and discountInput properties defined in the header (.h), or the implementation file? (.m)

Comment: If you have custom UITableViewCells you could use tags to access the UITextField and the input.

Comment: @mMo I added in the .h file of my customTableViewCell.

Comment: @Razgriz - Please add screen shot of your tableview for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

`SearchResultTableViewCell* cell = (SearchResultTableViewCell*)[searchResults cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 0):

In MVC ([Model View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html)), views visually display information from the models. From your code, it looks like you are asking your views (`UITableViewCell`'s) for information that should be (and probably already is) stored in a model class. The model objects that your tableview is displaying could look something like this:

```
@interface Sale
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *quantity;
...
@end
```

In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you are probably configuring the cells and also assigning an appropriate value to the `name`, `quantity` and `discountInput` textfields.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...
    Sale *sale = [self.sales objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameTextField.text = sale.itemName;
    ...
}
```

Since you associate a model with a cell at a given index path (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), you could also associate a given index path with a model. So instead of asking each view for its properties, you could store the rows of the selected cells and find the models corresponding to those rows.

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexPaths) {
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    Sale *sale = self.sales[row];
    ... 
}
```

Then you are handling the communication between views and models correctly and your code will most likely become a little simpler to read.

Comment: Just to confirm, I need to create a class `Sale` that is a subclass of `NSObject` that would contain the values I'll use for my tableRows?

Comment: Also, is `sales` the tableView?

Comment: It depends on how your data looks. I assumed (from your question) that it had something to do with sales. Choose what makes the most sense for you. In my (simplified) example, I also assumed that all model (Sale) objects were stored in an `NSArray` property called `sales`.

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableViewCell` is an UIView and it only knows about its child `UIViews`. So you can't really access the properties `quantity` and `discountInput`. You probably have an array which you use to set the values in the fields of the `UITableViewCell`, if so access that array and get the values. Otherwise your best bet is to set tags to the `quantity` and `discountInput` fields and access those views using tags. Like so

```
viewOfQuantity = [myTableViewCell viewWithTag:tagForQuantity];
viewOfDiscountInput = [myTableViewCellviewWithTag:tagDiscountInput ];
```

Then you can access the values in the views.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have an array where I get the values I use for the `tableViewCell` and I have no problem get the values. The problem is that I can't get the values the user inputs in the `textFields`.

Comment: Did you try setting tags to the views? Then access the views with the sample code in my answer